# Inverse probability weighted estimation of censored longitudinal data in R?

Tags: missing-data, panel-data

I'm looking for a package for estimating the mean of a longitudinal response under monotone dropout using a "state-of-the-art" method based on GEEs, in `R` (AIPW methods, doubly robust, whatever you want to call it). I've been Googling pretty hard and haven't come up with anything useful.

So we are all on the same page, I have a sequence of censored, continuous random vectors $\mathbf Y_1, ..., \mathbf Y_n$ where $\mathbf Y_i = (Y_{i1}, ..., Y_{iJ})$ and am interested in estimating the mean response at time $J$. The data is subject to dropout, with dropout time $S_i$. Under MAR (missing at random) I think I can estimate $\mu_J = E(Y_J)$ as 
$$
\frac 1 n \sum_{i= 1} ^ n \frac{I(S_i = J) Y_{iJ}}{\pi(\mathbf Y_i)} \tag{$*$}
$$
where $\pi(\mathbf Y_i) = P(S_i = J | \mathbf Y_i)$ is the probability of making it to the end of the study, given $\mathbf Y_i$. I can assume a model for $\pi(\mathbf Y_i)$ (probably in terms of the hazard function) and under MAR I can estimate it pretty well in principle. So I could model the hazards using the observed data to estimate the weights and then plug them into that equation.

This estimator is not state-of-the-art as far as I know - it can have problems with the weights being too large and (I think) it has other problems as well. There's a large literature on estimating equation based methods that solve augmented estimating equations, which is in the same spirit but fixes the problems with $(*)$. The problem is I can't find any software to solve this in `R`. I've seen stuff aimed at MSMs (marginal structure models) and causal inference, but nothing specifically for longitudinal missing data with dropout.

Comment: shouldn't the fraction in front of your IPWEE estimator be $\sum_{I=1}^n (\pi(\mathbf{Y}_i))$ instead of $1/n$

Comment: I suspect there is no state of the art approach to the problem of estimating a response at a specific time. The reason is that GEE estimates a population average given a covariance structure. If many drop out prior to time $t$, the (unweighted) GEE assumes that fraction is not part of the population. Weighting could upweight other clusters who are like those who drop out, but I echo the concern over consistency issues (infinite weights). Have you considered marginalizing a mixed model or predictive models with a bootstrap instead? I feel they would be more applicable.

Comment: @AdamO You can check that the weights I give leads to an unbiased estimator, it being just the Horwitz-Thompson estimator. The weights are not optimal, in the sense that normalizing by the sum of the IPWs reduces the asymptotic variance, but it is still valid. Anyway, when I asked this question I had in mind an implementation of the AIPW estimator I saw in a talk by Davidian, but there was no usable software. At the time I was writing a paper and I did compare to things like mixed models, but I wanted to compare to this as well :)